# How to pass parameter via ajax mvc?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem as follow : click button delete , then show modal popup , in modal, i have one button is "OK", when i click button "OK" , process event click of button "OK", such as call action delete via ajax.
my code snippet.

```
      @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Ajax.ActionLink(" Delete", "", "", new { id = @item.UserProfileID }, new AjaxOptions()
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "GET",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                                UpdateTargetId = "",
                                OnSuccess = "ShowModal()"
                            }, new { @class = "fa fa-times btn btn-danger btn-xs", @id = "bt_del_profile" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

<div id="myModal" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="bt_del_ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowModal() {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    }

    $('#bt_del_ok').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Profile/DelProfile',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            //processData: false,
            data: { id: @item.UserProfileID },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("OK");
                },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert("Error delete");
             }
         });
    });

</script>
```

The problem in here `data: { id: @item.UserProfileID },` . I can not get ID in here although when i show devtool chrome , i see `<a class="fa fa-times btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-success="ShowModal()" href="/Home/Index/P000000002" id="bt_del_profile"> Delete</a>`
 Can you tell me about this? and give me some advices.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are using `@item.UserProfileID` within your java script, it's actually asp.net. If you had this value coming from javascript, you would use it like `data: { id: '12345' },`

Which means your code should be `data: { id: '@item.UserProfileID' }`. That should fix your problem.

**Some 'Ideas'**

You can change your show modal like this.

```
<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="bt_del_ok" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then change your ShowModal like below.

```
function ShowModal(userProfileId) {
    $(".myModal").prop('id', userProfileId);
    $(".myModal").modal('show');
}
```

Then in delete event;

```
 var userProfileId =  $(".myModal").prop('id');
 data: { id:userProfileId },
```

Comment: Oh no , It get error `The name 'item' does not exist in the current context` . I have used but it's not work, ago.

Comment: That's a different issue though. I can see @item is defined in your for loop. So you need to pass `@item.UserProfileID` as a parameter to ShowModel() or something.

Comment: Also this line is wrong too. `@Ajax.ActionLink(" Delete", "", "", new { id = @item.UserProfileID }, new AjaxOptions()`

Comment: Yes, the problem in here , i must pass `@item.UserProfileID` as a parameter and assign variable at `data: { id: variable }` , some ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, you try pass `@item.UserProfileID`  assign to id modal ,It's look great but it's not working , i debug not see UserProfileID in here `data: { id:userProfileId },`

Comment: It's not get Id at `@Ajax.ActionLink(" Delete", "", "", new { id = @item.UserProfileID }, new AjaxOptions()
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "GET",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                                UpdateTargetId = "",
                                OnSuccess = "ShowModal(@item.UserProfileID)"
                            }, new { @class = "fa fa-times btn btn-danger btn-xs", @id = "bt_del_profile" })`

Comment: Did you fix the `@item.UserProfileID` syntax as I pointed out before?

Comment: as you say `@Ajax.ActionLink(" Delete", "", "", new { id = @item.UserProfileID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "", OnSuccess = "ShowModal(?????? ID )" }, new { @class = "fa fa-times btn btn-danger btn-xs", @id = "bt_del_profile" })`

Comment: Which means you have not fixed it. :) This line `@Ajax.ActionLink(" Delete", "", "", new { id = @item.UserProfileID }` should be `@Ajax.ActionLink(" Delete", "", "", new { id = '@item.UserProfileID' }`

Comment: No, this is wrong , error as `CS1012: Too many characters in character literal` . Are you sure ? .. Thank you

Comment: The problem not `@Ajax.ActionLink(" Delete", "", "", new { id = "@item.UserProfileID" }`  , problem pass parameter in here `OnSuccess = "ShowModal(??????)"`  . I try more way but it's not work

Comment: Hang on.. oh.. this AjaxHelper.. Just noticed it. Your code has to be `OnSuccess = "ShowModal("+ item.UserProfileID +")"`. Ignore my previous comment about Ajax syntax.

Comment: Well, I try as you more minutes ago, but get `Uncaught ReferenceError: P000000001 is not defined` at function ShowModal , It can get ID as ShowModal(P0000000001) , but not show modal , I think function ShowModal not work , as assign id to modal .~~

Comment: Did you add `class="modal fade myModal"` to your modal window? I can't see your code. You should be able to fix it now by yourself.

Comment: Dear Kosala W,  Ofcourse, i done, but it's not work , still get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: P000000001 is not defined`  .@@

Comment: When do you get this error? You need to do a bit or reasearch by yourself too. There was a syntax error in my code. `$(".myModal").id` should have been `$(".myModal").prop('id')`

Comment: Dear Kosala W, I do not take this way (first of topic), I founded way other by myself `(put a button with onclick = "showmodal(@item.id) , function showmodal(id) {assign value hidden, show modal} , then finally bind bt_del_ok)`. Anyway thank you so much , you're a good code snip. 
Happy code and thank you again.I'll mark your answer for issue .:D